# Which wonders can I not speed up with a Great Engineer in Civ 5 BNW?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings, civilization-5-brave-new-world

In Civilization V BNW it is possible to speed up the production of a city with a Great Engineer. This is particularly convenient when building a wonder; it can be finished in one turn in most cases.

This, however, apparently doesn't work for the Apollo Program or the Manhattan Project. Also spaceship parts cannot be constructed like that.

Most other wonders (world or national) can be rushed. To better plan my strategy in the next game: **which wonders can I not rush with a Great Engineer?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't hurry Manhattan Project, Apollo Project, and World Congress projects as they are projects rather than wonders.